# dial unix /run/guest-services/docker.sock: connect: connection refused

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker and Docker Desktop on Xubuntu, however, when I run the command "docker compose up", I get this error:

```
"Error response from daemon: dial unix /run/guest-services/docker.sock: connect: connection refused."
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: (You do not normally need Docker Desktop on native Linux; using the standalone Docker Engine may be easier.)